# Inequality proof $ay + bz + cx < 1$ with conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

> **Question:** Given that for all $a,b,c,x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $a+x = b + y = c + z = 1$, show that $ay + bz +cx < 1$.

---

**Attempts:** Using AM-GM and squaring all sides of the given equality and rearranging is something I feel maybe be important, although I have been unsuccessful in doing so. Another idea was to consider cases, although that is certainly not going to work as there is definitely a more elegant way of going about it.

I managed to get to a point where $ay + xy + b = bz + yz + c = cx + zx + a = 1$ although I believe this is also a dead-end.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By AM-GM (!), $$bz\le b^az^x\le ab+xz$$
Then $$ay+bz+cx\le ay+ab+xz+xc=a+x=1$$

Comment: I don't understand why $b^az^x \leq ab + xz$ :( everything else makes sense it's just this

Comment: $a+x=1$ so the weighted AM-GM inequality holds. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Generalizations

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $a,x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $0.25^{0.5}= 0.5>0.25$.

Comment: @Chrystomath  Sorry. You are right. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**

$$ay+bz+cx = (a+x)y-xy + (b+y)z-yz + (c+z)x-zx$$ $$= x+y+z-xy-yz-zx$$

You are left to prove that this is always $<1$ for $x,y,z \in (0,1)$.

Comment: i am sorry, but how do you prove that it is <1

Comment: It's a nice proof! +1  @Quantum $x+y+z-xy-xz-yz$ is a linear function of $x$, of $y$ and of $z$, which says it's enough to check $\{x,y,z\}\subset\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg i didn't quite understand that

Comment: @Quantum A linear function gets a maximal value for an extreme value of his variable. Are you agree?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes i got it , Thank you  for explanation,nice proof!

Comment: @Quantum You are welcome! Good luck!

Comment: @Quantum Another way to conclude is to develop $(1-x)(1-y)(1-z) \geq 0$ : you get $1-xyz \geq x+y+z-xy-yz-zx$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe that is also nice!~

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

$$1=(a+x)(b+y)(c+z)=abc+xyz+abz+acy+bcx+xyc+xzb+yza>$$
$$>ay(c+z)+bz(a+x)+cx(b+y)=ay+bz+cx.$$

Answer (score -1):

Substitute $a=1-x$. Then the expression $ay+bz+cx$ becomes linear in $x\in(0,1)$, hence you only have to check that the (non-strict) inequality is valid for extremal values of $x$, i.e. for $x=0$ and $x=1$. Argue similarly with $y$ and $z$. Then you are left with checking a finite number of cases.